# Automated package submission errors on CRAN, though the package builds and passes all checks locally

Tags: r, cran

I am attempting to submit a package to CRAN, but it is failing some automated checks: https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/influenceR_0.1.3_20230517_194638/Debian/00check.log

I am able to build the package from source successfully and it passes all the submission checks, so I am not sure how to address this error.
I will be grateful for ideas if anyone has any.

The test below passes:

```
...
✔  checking compiled code
✔  checking examples
✔  checking for unstated dependencies in 'tests'
─  checking tests
✔  Running 'testthat.R'
─  checking PDF version of manual ... [12s] OK
✔  checking HTML version of manual
N  checking for non-standard things in the check directory
   Found the following files/directories:
     ''NULL''
N  checking for detritus in the temp directory
   Found the following files/directories:
     'lastMiKTeXException'
─  Done with R CMD check
─  Cleaning up files and user
```

as do `devtools::check_win_devel()` and

`devtoolscheck()`:`

```
...
── R CMD check results ──────────────────────────────────────────── influenceR 0.1.2 ────
Duration: 16.7s

0 errors ✔ | 0 warnings ✔ | 0 notes ✔
```

Given this, I am not sure how to fix the error.

Following the suggestions below, I fixed the error and submitted, but I still get the following error:

https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/influenceR_0.1.4_20230517_224845/Debian/00check.log

Comment: it looks like from the checks there might be some broken links? can you remove them? I would suggest setting up a github repo and make github actions to test your build on multiple OS before submission

Comment: You might want to ask this question on `r-package-devel@r-project.org` ...

Comment: Isn't "N" indicating a 'note' rather than a 'warning'? If so, you are done & can submit just fine.   The info suggests this is just crud from trying to build the LaTeX files for the man pages, and that's not relevant to package acceptance.

Comment: Thanks all! I filed the broken links, and ran some new tests using `R CMD BUILD` followed by `R CMD check`, and `devtools::check_win_devel()`. I just resubmitted it. We'll see if it goes through.

Comment: This was a namespace collision issue. It has been fixed via: https://github.com/khanna-lab/influenceR/commit/e84501b8a208eaae4a1da561c289522c4ca18129.
The package compiles now.