# Found the following files/directories: ''NULL'' when I run devtools::check_rhub

Tags: r, devtools, cran, submission

When I'm running devtools:check_rhub I'm receiving the following note:

`❯ checking for non-standard things in the check directory ... NOTE Found the following files/directories: ''NULL''`

I am unable to find this NULL file/directory anywhere, even with the ls() command in RStudio. I even deleted my local repo and re-cloned it, but this note persists.

Anyone knows if this is a bug/crash?
If don't, how can I solve it?

*UPDATE*: As noted in [R-hub issue #560](https://github.com/r-hub/rhub/issues/560), this could be due to something in R-hub and not on my package. According to R-hub maintainer, this should be ignored.

Comment: Seems similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76275389/automated-package-submission-errors-on-cran-though-the-package-builds-and-passe. That was caused by a particular package conflict. In order to know what's going on we'd need a minimal reproducible example we can run to re-create and diagnosis the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's similiar but idk if is the same, cause the notes are differents.
According to R-hub maintainer, both are problems related to R-hub package and not on my one.